# Can I create RSS feed in mobile app

Tags: rss

I want to create a RSS feed from mobile app ex: android where I can post the data that all people immediately can see it. Can you please help..

Comment: Too basic, you need to research more on the subject before you ask a question here.

Comment: Is it too basic ?, then can you give me how can I post a RSS feed from mobile app (NOT HOW TO DISPLAY RSS feed in app)

Comment: What kind of objects are you trying to post in the RSS feed? Strings, Images, Hyperlinks, eg?

Comment: Just a text for now..I mean string

Comment: Then, you're probably better off to do as Azzoz says, but to convert to an xml of strings, and send to a server, and have the server give you a response text of the rss feed (hosted on your server).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to put RSS feed in server or website and your app can display or post to that website.

Comment: Thank you Azzoz Al-Hasani...I'm new to this RSS feed.Let me tell you what I understood. I'll create a textfield in android and enter data in it and store it in server database(I've a doubt that for RSS feed we need to maintain a database)...From the server database we can Read RSS feed. is that correct. Can you help me if you have a link of example how can I create an rss feed in the server database( we don't have a website) . And how to send data from mobile app please.